# Animating react (functional) component based on props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

I'm new to React, and am confused on how to think about and manage animations. I have a functional component that receives a property `pieceType`.

- I want it to use animation A when it mounts,
- and if `pieceType` changes, I want it to use animation B for changing from `pieceType=1` to `pieceType=2`,
- and animation C for changing the other way.

I tried using React Transition Group and Framer Motion, but neither of them provide a solution for specifying an in-place animation on changing `props`, which makes me wonder if I am thinking about this the right way -- instead of a functional component, should I use a class? It doesn't seem right to store the incoming `props` as `state` variables, as changing the state will trigger a re-render, right? If I store arbitrary variables (not `state`) in the instance of my class, what is the right time in the lifecycle to update them, and can I rely on this?

Some abstracted code below:

```
function Circle(props) {
  return (
    <div className={ `circle ${props.pieceType}` }>
    </div>
  );
}

class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pieceType: null
    }
  }

  render() {
    const content = this.state.pieceType ?
                    <Circle pieceType={this.state.pieceType}/> :
                    null;
    return (
      <div className="square" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        { content }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      size: 8,
      squares : Array(8**2).fill(null),
      isPlayer1: true
    }
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    let squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = this.state.isPlayer1 ? 1 : 2;
    this.setState( {
      squares: squares,
      isPlayer1: !this.state.isPlayer1
    });
  }

  render() {
    let style = {"--gridSize" : this.state.size};
    let cells = [];
    for(let i=0; i<(this.state.size**2); i++) {
      cells.push(
        <Square onClick={ ()=>this.handleClick(i) }/>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div className="board" style={style}>
        {cells}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Board/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Apologies if this is a bit muddled (it is muddled in my head) -- any pointers towards abstract structure and how to think about this would be greatly appreciated! I want to avoid a simple `css` `class` approach, as I'd like to manage all the animations in the same place (mounting, un-mounting, and transitioning in-place) -->[edit] from my understanding, un-mounting can be tricky with a css class-name approach as the component is removed before the animation runs.

Comment: Good question! It will help people help you if you update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). :-)

Comment: What kind of animations are you trying to do?

Comment: *"I want to avoid a simple css class approach..."* I want to gently push back on that. :-) CSS is great at animations, what is it about these animations that makes you want to use JavaScript to handle them?

Comment: As far as I understand, animation when un-mounting a component poses a challenge for css class-based animations, since the element is removed before the animation starts. Based on this assumption, I inferred I should use a library to help me with this part. If this is the case, I would like to specify all the animation logic through the library instead of some transitions defined in css and some in javascript .. (updating the question too). Does this make sense, or am I adding complexity with this approach?

Comment: So it's not something specific about the animations, it's just that your impression is that CSS class-based animations are hard with React? *"...am I adding complexity with this approach?"* I don't know. :-) My instinct is yes, but that's all it is. Hopefully someone does know and they'll help...

Comment: Not that they're hard, it just feels a little limited since I am not explicitly controlling adding/removing elements. In the code above, the `Circle` component passes `props.pieceType` as a class to the `div` it renders. I can add css animations on those classes, but this won't work when I want to remove/unmount a `circle` component.. Was hoping there is a neat way to keep everything relating to state change in one place, as a foundation to build more complex transitions upon.. but your instinct might just be right, I might have fallen down a rabbit hole :)

Comment: I do strongly urge you to make your example above runnable (see links in first comment). You're nearly there, you basically just need to add the CSS (and unfortunately the version of Babel that Stack Snippets uses doesn't know `**`, you'll have to replace `8**2` with `64` and `this.state.size**2` with `this.state.size*this.state.size`).